# Cannot assign a char array to my struct array's third slot

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAMELENGTH 20
#define MAXPEOPLE 10

struct people{
    char name[NAMELENGTH];

    int ratings[MAXPEOPLE];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct people *men[MAXPEOPLE];
    strcpy(men[2]->name,"pie");

    return 0;
}
```

It crashes upon trying to assign any value to men[2]->name
men[]->name is a char array and the first two slots men[0]->name and men[1]->name work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only created an array of pointers, not an array of `struct people`:

```
struct people *men[MAXPEOPLE];
```

This only creates an array of pointers, but the pointers don't yet point to anything because you haven't allocated any space for them.  This means that you are copying into a `name` that doesn't actually exist.  To create an array of `struct people` you want:

```
struct people men[MAXPEOPLE];
strcpy(men[2].name,"pie");
```

Answer (score 1):

`men[2]` is not the pointer so when you use `->` operator you try to dereference something that is not a pointer. You have to use `malloc` and then you can use the pointer that points to allocated space

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMELENGTH 20
#define MAXPEOPLE 10

struct people{
    char name[NAMELENGTH];

    int ratings[MAXPEOPLE];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct people *men[MAXPEOPLE];
    men[2] = malloc(sizeof(struct people));
    strcpy(men[2]->name,"pie");

    return 0;
}
```

Regarding the fact that it works (for you) for first 2 'slots', it really shouldn't as those pointers are undefined also. For me it works only for index 0.